# Can some tell me where is the error? saying $ not defined, object expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

saying $ not defined, object expected.. actually i want to verify if all set of radio button check when a button is  clicked! help plz

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).on('click', 'form', function () {

    var validate = true;
   var unanswered = new Array();

   // Loop through available sets
   $('.qselections').each(function () {
    // Question text
    var question = $(this).prev().text();
    // Validate
    if (!$(this).find('input').is(':checked')) {
        // Didn't validate ... dispaly alert or do something
        unanswered.push(question);

        validate = false;
    }
});

if (unanswered.length > 0) {
    msg = "Please answer the following questions:\n" + unanswered.join('\n'); 
    alert(msg);
}
return validate;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you included a reference to jQuery? Have you included that reference before any other scripts?

Comment: i have updated the code. i have put the script in my body itself after</form>.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to include the jquery.js file in your markup before your code?

Comment: Also as well as the ready function, make sure you are defining Jquery before you are enacting that script

Answer (score 0):

A generally accepted way to set up your script references is as follows (there are others, this isn't the be-all-end-all):

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="MyScriptFile.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $(document).on('click', 'form', function () {

                    var validate = true;
                   var unanswered = new Array();

                   // Loop through available sets
                   $('.qselections').each(function () {
                    // Question text
                    var question = $(this).prev().text();
                    // Validate
                    if (!$(this).find('input').is(':checked')) {
                        // Didn't validate ... dispaly alert or do something
                        unanswered.push(question);

                        validate = false;
                    }
                });

                if (unanswered.length > 0) {
                    msg = "Please answer the following questions:\n" + unanswered.join('\n'); 
                    alert(msg);
                }
                return validate;
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This way you can be sure that (1) your page is loaded before any scripts try to do scripty things and (2) you have included jQuery before other scripts which may want to use it.

This is not foolproof, and you may (eventually) need to use something like [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/) or as a simpler step the `defer` attribute.

Comment: you mean i have to include the $(function() { before $(document).on('click', 'form', function () { ???

Comment: All of that should be wrapped in the anonymous function.  See my edit.

Comment: The way you're trying to return the value of `validate` is awkward, too. The jQuery `on` method is an event delegate. You can't so easily return values that way.

Comment: To be clear... it all has to be wrapped in an anonymous function because of the `if(unanswered....)`?

Answer (score 0):

1.Have you included `Jquery` lib in `first script tag` in your `head` section. In that case only your jquery based code will execute.

2.Did you `wrap the code into $(document).ready()` function.

3 Are you using `PHP` at your corners. So need to replace `$` with `Jquery.`

Comment: point 3 is impossible: either PHP would've raised fatal errors (`$(` is invalid PHP code) + replacing with `jQuery` would be better than using `Jquery` :)